# Can't access my website via domain name anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, keystonejs

I have created a KeystoneJS-based website on Google Cloud Platform a couple of months ago.

IP-address (IPv4): `35.209.129.188:3000`

Domain name: `seebelarus.by`

I didn't do anything, I didn't change any settings but now I can't reach my website via domain name. Only IP. Are there any ways to see what settings changed and how can I fix it?

Here's info about DNS:
[image]

Comment: It's domain name is '188.129.209.35.bc.googleusercontent.com' now. can you please send the output of this command cat /etc/hosts cat /etc/hostname.

Comment: `188.129.209.35.bc.googleusercontent.com` it's a [PTR record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) and it's for different purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The cause of this issue is DNS misconfiguration** while switching from registrar's DNS servers to Google Cloud DNS. There are no NS records for your domain `seebelarus.by` at the moment:

```
$ dig NS seebelarus.by @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS seebelarus.by @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 19578
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;seebelarus.by.                 IN      NS

;; Query time: 123 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu May 28 12:57:06 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42

$ dig NS seebelarus.by @8.8.4.4

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS seebelarus.by @8.8.4.4
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 12620
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;seebelarus.by.                 IN      NS

;; Query time: 85 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu May 28 12:57:15 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42

$ dig NS seebelarus.by @1.1.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS seebelarus.by @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 14617
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;seebelarus.by.                 IN      NS

;; Query time: 727 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu May 28 12:57:21 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

This domain was registered by [Open Contact, Ltd](https://domain.by/en/info-about/):

```
$ whois seebelarus.by
Domain Name: seebelarus.by
Registrar: Open Contact, Ltd
Person: HIDDEN!
Email: HIDDEN! Details are available at http://www.cctld.by/whois/
Name Server: ns1.domain.by
Name Server: ns2.domain.by
Updated Date: 2019-11-07
Creation Date: 2015-05-03
Expiration Date: 2021-05-03

-------------------------------------------
Service provided by Reliable Software, Ltd.
```

**To solve your issue** and switch to Google Cloud DNS you should follow steps below:

1. go to [registrar's domain control panel](https://domain.by/en/info-about/) and set as new DNS servers for your domain, for your domain you should replace:

   ```
   ns1.domain.by
   ns2.domain.by
   ```

   with:

   ```
   ns-cloud-b1-googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-b2-googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-b3-googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-b4-googledomains.com
   ```
2. go to Google Cloud DNS and remove from zone `NS` records:

   ```
   ns1.domain.by
   ns2.domain.by
   ```

   you don't need them anymore, there should be only related to Google NS records:

   ```
   ns-cloud-b1-googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-b2-googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-b3-googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-b4-googledomains.com
   ```

   keep unchanged `A` record and it's a good time to add `CNAME` record for `www.seebelarus.by`.

More details you can find in the documentation [Cloud DNS Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart).

After that, you should wait 24-48 hours for [DNS propagation](https://www.siteground.com/kb/what_is_dns_propagation_and_why_it_takes_so_long/). You can check status of DNS propagation for your domain with online tools like [dnsmap.io](https://dnsmap.io/), [https://dnschecker.org/](http://dnschecker.org) or similar.

**UPDATE**

DNS configuration looks good now:

```
$ whois seebelarus.by
Domain Name: seebelarus.by
Registrar: Open Contact, Ltd
Person: HIDDEN!
Email: HIDDEN! Details are available at http://www.cctld.by/whois/
Name Server: ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com
Updated Date: 2020-05-29
Creation Date: 2015-05-03
Expiration Date: 2021-05-03
```

and

```
$ dig NS seebelarus.by

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS seebelarus.by
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56451
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;seebelarus.by.                 IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
seebelarus.by.          21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
seebelarus.by.          21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
seebelarus.by.          21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
seebelarus.by.          21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri May 29 12:16:46 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 163

$ host seebelarus.by
seebelarus.by has address 35.209.129.188
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I received the domain name from domain.by, so I thought I need to specify ```NS``` records: ```ns1.domain.by ns2.domain.by```

Comment: Have you changed setting at the registrar's side? As I can see, you still have this issue.

Comment: I didn't change anything at all before asking questions here. I've followed your advice and now I'm waiting for 24-48 hours

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Please accept or upvote my answer if it was helpful for you to make it more helpful for community.

Answer (score 0):

No DNS results are found after lookup on your domain name, you must check your DNS in the domain name configuration and set an A record with that IP address.